# Create modular enterprise application in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a project where we have to create a modular application using React JS for our business application. Basically, we would like to build a menu based React "host" application that can on click of a menu button load up an application referenced to that menu. Each of these sub applications, would be different react projects, as npm packages (I suppose). The host application would have a redux store, and manage features like authentication, authorization, etc. and components worked on by different developers will simply be loaded into the main layout. I have read about using the create-react-app and create-react-hook packages, but I'm not so sure what is the best way to start.

Can someone please provide some ideas or best practices for building and setting up a React application like this?

Comment: This question is too vague and broad in scope for this site.

Comment: @KenWhite how is this question vague and broad at the same time? I tried to provide as much details and describe my technical problem in the question. What exactly is vague or broad in your opinion about my question? I am looking for answer to my question.

Comment: Because there is nothing remotely specific about it. *How do I create a modular enterprise application?* is no more specific than *How do I create a new app like Instagram in VBA?*. This site is for **specific questions** related to problems you're having with code or a programmers tool. *some ideas or best practices* is not specific at all.  Your question is broad enough that someone could write a book about it. See [What kinds of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For simple sub appliactions, develop as normal pwa with react-router. use different router for your sub applications.

For complicated sub applications, develop sub applications individualy and deploy on different port, then use nginx to proxy specific router to them. Create a backend application for authentication, jwt is a good choice.

Comment: thanks, but my question is around setting up modules which are different applications that can be hosted in a parent application. This doesn't provide me with any information on how to do that.

Comment: For simple application, use modules as npm package in parent application, or develop them deirectly in the parent application.

For complicated, just I said. develop your sub applications and package theme, then deploy in different port. In parent application use router like `/app1` then use nginx to proxy `/app1` to your sub application app1

Comment: Oh, ssr is also a good choice, [next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs) is a good way to do this.